# Java confusion with hh:mm

Tags: java

my project prompts the user for a string in form hh:mm.
Then i need to separate the hh:mm into hours and minutes which i think i did

```
String Hour = string.substring(0,2);
String Minutes = string.substring(3,5);
```

Now i need to make sure that the hour is from 5<= hour < 22.
But I can't do equality with a string so i used parseInt to convert it to an int and do the equality with that. But it drops leading zeroes which i need to keep in my code.

How do i go about doing this

Comment: Javascript != Java. (I've fixed the question tag for you.)

Comment: What's the example input , could you share with us?

Comment: If you are using this data in string format after doing equality simplest way will be to add `0` for hours and minutes less than 10.

Comment: @survivorr There are three answers for you to consider for upvoting and/or accepting

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [Simple Date Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String input= "05:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date = sdf.parse(input);
```

Comment: *Now i need to make sure that the hour is from 5<= hour < 22.* - does not answer this

Comment: The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for `parseInt` try

```
    String line = "23:59";

    String arr [] = line.split(":");
    if (Integer.parseInt(arr[0]) < 5 || Integer.parseInt(arr[0]) >= 22) {
        System.out.println("wrong hour");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## `String::split`

Generally, for splitting strings into parts, use the [`String::split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) command. See the Question [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/642706) for much discussion.

```
String[] parts = "07:11".split( ":" );
```

> Arrays.toString( parts ): [07, 11]

But I do *not* recommend this approach in your case. Read on.

## `LocalTime`

Java offers a purpose-built class for you: [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). This class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone. The clock is a single generic 24-hour day that ignores anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Your input such as `07:11` happens to comply with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The java.time classes use these formats by default when parsing or generating strings representing date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "07:11" );
```

From there you may interrogate for the hour portion or the minute portion.

```
int hourOfDay = localTime.getHour();
int minuteOfHour = localTime.getMinute();
```

But your real goal is to compare the time to see if it is between 5 AM and 10 PM. For example, is this true: `5 AM < 07:11 < 10 PM`. So no need to tear apart the time into pieces. Instead, make your comparison more directly, and in a more self-documenting way, using the `LocalTime` class.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 5 , 0 );  //  5 AM = 05:00.
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 22 , 0 );  // 10 PM = 22:00.

Boolean isBetween = 
    ( ! localTime.isBefore( start ) ) 
    && 
    localTime.isBefore( stop ) 
;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/ebd2sm).

About that comparison statement:

- The first part asks “Is our target either exactly on the start or after the start?”. A shorter way to ask that is, “Is our target *not* before the start?”. If “not before” then logically it must either be exactly on or after.
- The second part asks if our target is before the stop rather than “is equal to or before”. This means we are using the **Half-Open** approach to defining a span of time. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This is commonly used in date-time work. I believe using it consistently throughout your code base and business logic removes much of the confusion and ambiguity that arises from spans of time.